# Select all from A where attribute exists in B

Tags: relational-theory, exists

I have a question involving relational algebra. Suppose I have two relations A and B, where B has a foreign key that references A.

Using relational algebra, how do I select all tuples from A where variable X exists in B? Example:

#### Relation 1

```
Cars(car_id,model)
```

#### Relation 2

```
Ford(car_id,year)
```

How do I select from Cars, all the tuples where id exists in Ford? Example:

```
Cars  car_id  model
      -------------
       1    a
       2    b
       3    c

Ford  car_id   year
      1        2000
      3        2002
```

What I would like is: select all from cars where id exists in Ford, which returns:

```
Result:  car_id  model
        --------------
         1    a
         3    c
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The (somewhat trivial) answer seems to be:

```
Cars ⋉ Ford
```

[Relational algebra, semijoin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Semijoin_.28.E2.8B.89.29.28.E2.8B.8A.29) (Wikipedia)

Alternatively (in response to a comment):

```
πR(R ⋈ S)
```